# tradeoff routes and views rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

here it's routes.db

```
resources :licenses  do 
 resources :sublicenses do
  resources :time_licenses
 end
end
```

Then there is a client application that calls time_licenses_controller for creating new time_licenses, the controller responds with a json file, but i don't need to show any view.

Somewhere else instead i need to show to the client an index file including all time_licenses for every sublicense.
That's the path

```
license/:id/sublilicense/:id/time_lincenses
```

Now i have a problem with the routes. When i call the create on time_licenses_controller i get this error:

```
No route matches "/time_licenses.js"
```

that i can solve changing the routes.db file like this

```
resources :time_licenses
resources :licenses  do 
 resources :sublicenses
end
```

but in that case i get the same error linking the index view.

What do you suggest me? Do i have to create two different controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using nested resources, you will always need to specify license and sublicense while specifying the path to timelicense.
Your path helpers will be:

```
license_sublicense_timelicense_path(@license, @sublicense, @timelicense) and so on
```

You can get the path names for the timelicense by

```
rake routes
```

Refer [rails guides - nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for any doubts.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i get it. The only annoying thing is that my client has to send a request like /licenses/1/sublicenses/1/time_licenses.js but in the end i don't need  all those parameters.